# Homology of $\Sigma_{2}\times S^{1}$?

Tags: algebraic-topology

I'm quite at a loss with this...I want to use Mayer-Vietoris with open covers $A=\Sigma_{2}\times (S^{1}\setminus \{p\})$ and $B=\Sigma_{2}\times (S^{1}\setminus \{q\})$
so that $A$ and $B$ both deformation retract to $\Sigma_{2}$ and $A\cap B$ deformation retracts to $\Sigma_{2}\times\{0,1\}$, but I don't understand how to think about the inclusion maps $H_{n}(A\cap B) \hookrightarrow H_{n}(A)\bigoplus H_{n}(B)$.

$\Sigma_2$ denotes the orientable surface of genus two.

Comment: What is $\Sigma_2$?

Comment: @AlexBecker Probably [the orientable surface of genus $2$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Double_torus_illustration.png). It would be nice to have this explicit in the question, I agree.

Comment: @DylanMoreland That was my working hypothesis. I've drawn about 20 of those today though, so I want to be sure I'm not just seeing them everywhere.

Comment: Yes, $\Sigma_{2}$ is the orientable surface of genus 2.

Comment: @user36025, please add that information to the body of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $A$ and $B$ are both homotopic to $\Sigma_2$, and so $H_n(A \cap B) \cong H_n(A) + H_n(B)$ for all $n$, if you choose your embeddings $i$ and $j$ wisely.

Comment: So by cellular homology I have $H_{0}(\Sigma_{2}) \simeq H_{2}(\Sigma_{2}) \simeq \mathbb{Z}$ and $H_{1}(\Sigma_{2}) \simeq \mathbb{Z}^{4}$ where $H_{0}$ is generated by the vertex $v$, $H_{2}$ by the 2-cell $F$, and $H_{1}$ by the 4 loops in the 1-skeleton $e_{1},\dots ,e_{4}$. So the map $H_{1}(A\cap B) \hookrightarrow H_{1}(A)\bigoplus H_{1}(B)$ takes a generator $(e_{i},e_{j})$ to $\dots$what? :(

Comment: These embedding are what I'm confused about. :/

Comment: Well, $H_1(A)$ should be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^2$, so should have two generators $(e_1^A, e_2^A)$; similarly for $H_1(B)$. And $H_1(A \cap B) \cong H_1(A) \oplus H_1(B)$, so what's the most obvious map you can think of between $H_1(A) \oplus H_1(B)$ and $H_1(A) \oplus H_1(B)$?

Comment: If $A$ is homotopic to $\Sigma_{2}$, then $H_{1}(A) \simeq \mathbb{Z}^{4}$ according to topospaces (http://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/Homology_of_compact_orientable_surfaces ). I'll try to think about this again tonight.